# Why can't lone pairs remain in unhybridised orbitals?

Tags: orbitals

I have seen that lone pairs are almost invariably counted for determining the hybridisation of an atom.

My question is why can't they remain in unhybridised orbitals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does ammonia have sp hybridization?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/why-does-ammonia-have-sp-hybridization). Though it is not an exact duplicate, that would be the answer to your question in any other case.

Comment: @ringo Related yes, duplicate no. Also I find the answers given there highly unsatisfactory.

Comment: There are many examples of lone pairs in orbitals that are unhybridized.  See [this earlier answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/why-does-bond-angle-decrease-in-the-order-h%E2%82%82o-h%E2%82%82s-h%E2%82%82se/14995#14995) for several examples.  Another example, phosphine is discussed [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13907/how-does-lone-pair-of-a-central-atom-affect-the-dipole-moment/13915#13915).